# PHP Object Visibility

Tags: php, visibility

Okay, so I'm fairly new to PHP but this is vexing me.  I'm getting a "Cannot access protected property Database::$database" when I try to dump the var.  Why is $database not accessible from the $db object?  Am I misunderstanding the "private", "protected", and "public" keywords when it comes to objects?

```
class Database
{
    protected $database;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB", "root", "password");
    }
}
$db = new Database();
var_dump($db->database);
```

Comment: If you are trying to dump protected property then yes, you are misunderstanding something.

Comment: You also probably want to extend PDO instead of wrapping it...

Comment: @Charles could you please clarify? How am I wrapping PDO? How would I extend it?

Comment: @user1864576 Wrapping an object means you create a new object and add new methods to interface with the methods of the object you are wrapping. You can extend it by doing `class Database extends PDO`. This would allow you to instantiate Database and yet use it like a PDO object (i.e. `$database = new Database(); $database->prepare('SELECT...');` )

Answer (score 2):

Your protected property is only available inside the class (and extended classes...), so in methods in your class you can use `$this->database` but outside of the class, you would need a getter to access its value, something like:

In the class:

```
public function getDB()
{
  return $this->database;
}
```

Outside of the class:

```
var_dump($db->getDB());
```

Comment: Granted, the above will work, but you should at least add scope (public) to the getDB() method, for clarity.

Comment: Ah, I see this now. So what would be the benefit of sticking the property in a getter as opposed to making it public?

Comment: @user1864576 You cannot accidentally change it, you can add validating stuff in the putter, etc.

Comment: It's always better to access 'member variables' using public accessors, as they can do more than simply return member variable values, they can be used to massage data. For example you can typecast  scalars to ensure strict datatypes. Also you can implement fluent interface by returning the object.

Comment: @Mike Purcell Changed for clarity, although I fail to see what good can come of making that property available like that in the first place :-)

Comment: Depends on the API. It's common place to call on `getDbo()` to access that object's public accessors. It's up to the object to protect itself.

Answer (score 0):

they can be public, protected, or private.

please see the php manual for examples

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0):

Below, "Item" = property (class-scoped variable) or method, and "accessed" = called (methods) or used/changed directly (properties).

- Items with **private** visibility can only be accessed within the class in which they are defined. **NOTE** Personally, I have found that it only causes grief to use private. Instead, use protected so that people can extend the class and use the item, unless you actually have a really good reason to make it private.
- Items with **protected** visibility can only be accessed within the class in which they are defined, as well as any classes that extend that class (i.e. child classes will inherit it)
- Items with **public** visibility may be accessed within the currently class, all child classes, and within the scope in which the object is available. *This is the default if you don't specifiy a visibility, but is it good to do so anyway for clarity.*

To access a private or protected property outside of the scope in which it is available, use a public getter/setter method.

EDIT: So to answer your question of why you are getting an error, you are calling var_dump() on the protected property *outside* of the class in which it is available. Because it is protected, it is not available in global scope. You can either move the var_dump() to a method inside the class (and remember to use $this when referring to the object from inside) or you can use a getter method to return the value and then var_dump() that.